# How to make a subquery in Sqlalchemy using not in with two fields?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I need filter using *not in* but in two fields.

```
q = db_session.query(Necessidade, WFLeilao, BidHeader, BidItemPrice, func.sbprecobruto(BidItemPrice.bid_number,BidItemPrice.line_number, Necessidade.identportal, type_=Float))
q = q.join(WFLeilao, and_(Necessidade.numeroportal == WFLeilao.leilao, Necessidade.numeroitemportal == WFLeilao.itemleilao))    
q = q.join(BidHeader, and_(BidHeader.bid_number == BidItemPrice.bid_number))    
q = q.join(BidItemPrice, and_(BidItemPrice.auction_header_id == WFLeilao.leilao, BidItemPrice.auction_line_number == WFLeilao.itemleilao, BidItemPrice.bid_number == WFLeilao.lance, BidItemPrice.line_number == WFLeilao.itemlance))    

subquery = db_session.query(ItfRetornoPedido.num_leilao_superbuy, ItfRetornoPedido.num_item_leilao_superbuy).filter_by(status_comprador=1).filter_by(acao='I').filter_by(empresa='NK').subquery()

q = q.filter(~(WFLeilao.leilao,Wfleilao.itemleilao).in_(subquery))
```

In oracle is possible, a similar example:

```
 Select *
  from table_a
 where (leilao, itemleilao) not in
       (Select num_leilao_superbuy, num_item_leilao_superbuy
          from table_b 
         where empresa = 'NK')
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution using *tuple_*

```
q = q.filter(~tuple_(WFLeilao.leilao, WFLeilao.itemleilao).in_(subquery))
```

Answer (score 1):

you can chain the query:

```
q = q.filter(~(WFLeilao.leilao.in_(subquery))) \
     .filter(~(Wfleilao.itemleilao.in_(subquery)))
```

Comment: Thank you. But I think that using tuple is better

Comment: Not just better, resulting `SQL` is semantically very different.

Comment: Yes! I mean `tuple_` worked for me and it was exactly I needed.